# What is the property CoreDispatcher.HasThreadAccess used for?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am new to working with Windows and I am trying to understand the APIs. Windows Runtime API provides the property CoreDispatcher.HasThreadAccess, but the description in the docs of what it is is very vague:

["Gets a value that specifies whether the event dispatcher provided by this instance of CoreWindow has access to the current thread or not."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.hasthreadaccess)

What does it mean when it returns false? When and why would a user-engineer use this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tells you whether the thread that your code is running on can safely update the UI.  Compare it to Control.InvokeRequired in Winforms and Dispatcher.CheckAccess in WPF.

When it returns false, you *must* use Dispatcher.RunAsync() to make sure your code runs on the right thread.

Comment: So is it safe to say it returns true when executed on the UI thread, and false when executed on any other thread?

Comment: That's pretty safe to say.

Comment: i am getting exception "A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)" when i check if(Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess){action();} while exception points on MainView.thanks in advance